# Do multiple ImageView's holding the same image create extra Drawable objects or Drawable instances?

Tags: android

I currently have a `ViewFlipper` that holds the same `ImageView` in each screen. The issue is that I have to create an `ImageView[]` array with a unique `ImageView` per screen in the `ViewFlipper` in order to add them to the `ViewFlipper` since I run into the child already has a parent issue when using the same `ImageView`. They all refer to the same resource in `R.drawable`.

My question is this: does every `ImageView` in the array create a separate instance of the drawable object or do they each simply contain a reference to the same drawable object? Also, are `ImageView` instances resource intensive? I'm worried that this would run into overhead issues, since this `ImageView` array isn't the only one.

Answer (score 5):

As far as [drawables loaded from the same resource share a common state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate%28%29)
it seems that android architects have thought of this question and the resources are used for 1 image only, so you won't get overhead in such way.
In addition: [BitmapDrawables created from the same resource will for instance share a unique bitmap stored in their ConstantState.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. It puts me at ease knowing the memory footprint won't explode when I use these things.